# Vba excel resumir código

Tags: excel, vba, optimización

Este es el código de excel vba que quiero reducir esta vez se agradecería ayuda

```
If Weekday(i, vbMonday) = 6 Or Weekday(i, vbMonday) = 7 Or Sheets("QUADRANTE").Cells(y - 1, x).Font.ColorIndex = 7 Then
    Sheets(mes).Range("B" & 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":B" & 11 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Sheets(mes).Range("B" & 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":B" & 11 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Font.Color = vbRed
    Sheets(mes).Range("J" & 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":J" & 11 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 48

End If

Sheets(mes).Range("C" & 1 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":G" & 1 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
Sheets(mes).Range("C" & 3 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":G" & 3 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
Sheets(mes).Range("C" & 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":G" & 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
Sheets(mes).Range("C" & 2 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5 & ":G" & 2 + 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5).Interior.ColorIndex =  35
```

Comment: Creo que falta algo de contexto a tu código ¿qué valor tiene `i`?

Comment: For i = fecha To FechaFin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qué tal, aunque desconozco el propósito puede quedar de ésta manera y resulta más legible:

```
Dim i_ As Long, j_ As long, colores_ As Variant
i_ = 7 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5
j_ = 11 + (Day(i) - 1) * 5
SET colores_ = Array(35, 15, 35, 15)

If Weekday(i, vbMonday) = 6 Or Weekday(i, vbMonday) = 7 Or Sheets("QUADRANTE").Cells(y - 1, x).Font.ColorIndex = 7 Then
    Sheets(mes).Range("B" & i_ & ":B" & j_).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Sheets(mes).Range("B" & i_ & ":B" & j_).Font.Color = vbRed
    Sheets(mes).Range("J" & i_ & ":J" & j_).Interior.ColorIndex = 48

End If

For z = 0 To 3
    Sheets(mes).Range("C" & (i_ + z) & ":G" & (i_ + z)).Interior.ColorIndex = colores_(z)
Next z
```

Answer (score -1):

creo que esto es lo que se le puede hacer:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets(MES)
'estableces la hoja mes como un objeto Worksheet
Dim dayLOne As Integer ' declaras la variable
If Weekday(I, vbMonday) = 6 Or Weekday(I, vbMonday) = 7 Or Sheets("QUADRANTE").Cells(y - 1, x).Font.ColorIndex = 7 Then
    dayLOne = (Day(I) - 1) * 5 ' asignas un valor sustituible a la variable.
    With sht.Range("B" & 7 + (dayLOne) * 5 & ":B" & 11 + (dayLOne) * 5)
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 39
        .Font.Color = vbRed
    End With
    sht.Range("J" & 7 + (dayLOne) & ":J" & 11 + (dayLOne)).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
End If
sht.Range("C" & 1 + 7 + (dayLOne) & ":G" & 1 + 7 + (dayLOne)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
sht.Range("C" & 3 + 7 + (dayLOne) & ":G" & 3 + 7 + (dayLOne)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
sht.Range("C" & 7 + (dayLOne) & ":G" & 7 + (dayLOne)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
sht.Range("C" & 2 + 7 + (dayLOne) & ":G" & 2 + 7 + (dayLOne)).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Las respuestas que solo incluyen código, requieren de alguna explicación para que no se consideran de baja calidad. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Comment: Hola Javi fer2, gracias mu amable por su observación, voy a tomarlo en cuenta la próxima.